# Ext JS 4.0 providing "unconventional" data to charts

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, extjs4, extjs

I have a store which always contains a single record. Lets say the record looks like this:

```
{'good': 5, 'bad': 2, 'neutral': 3}
```

How would I render that as a [Pie chart](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.chart.series.Pie)? Ext.js normally uses each record in a store as one point of the series. In my case, I have only one record and want it to be used as three points in the series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple options available to you. You can create a custom `Ext.data.reader.Reader` subclass that will convert your raw data into your formatted records, you can override the store's `loadRawData` method to convert JSON data into an `Ext.data.ResultSet`, or you can set a callback on the store's `load` method to get your record and manually convert it into your necessary record format. If you're going for reusability, I suggest making a Reader.

The `Reader#readRecords` method takes raw data and returns a ResultSet, which sounds exactly like what you're after. Take a look at the source from the Sencha docs website and you should be able to figure out where to go from there. Once you have your custom reader, pass it to your store's proxy during configuration and it *should* handle the work for you. If it doesn't automatically, you may need to call the store `loadRawData`, passing your JSON response.

Answer (score 3):

Split it into three records. You can create your own instances of Record and fill them with data using your original record as source.

Comment: So I need to create an additional Store for this PieChart. In the onLoad of the original Store, I would create records and stuff them into the 'new' Store? That sounds ridiculous.

Comment: That would be the idea. Ridiculous? I don't see why. Cerrtainly modyfing Chart class to be able to consume your non-standard data would take more work.

Comment: I've implemented it and it works. I'm not happy with this solution, though. A lot of code for a very trivial thing. Lets see is someone comes up with something more beautiful.